# How to make Youtube videos play from code without having the user to switch to that tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension where user can make playlists of songs. For that when I click on play button I need that new tab should open and the video should start playing but youtube video doesn't play without switching over to that tab. I tried to use the 'canplay' eventlistener but it also is called only when I switch over to that tab in which video is played. Can somebody help?

```js
console.log("Hello from content script!");
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
if(video) {
  video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    console.log("Video ended");
    //alert('Ended');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        "ended"
    );
  })
  video.addEventListener("canplay", function(event) {
      alert("noted");
      //video.play();
      let playbtn = document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-play-button ytp-button')[0];
      playbtn.click();
  })
} else {
  //console.error("Video element not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding I?&autoplay=1 to the end of the youtube links?

Comment: I just now tried to add '?&autoplay=1' but I don't know why this part is removed when link is loaded and the same situation persists. I also tried to run this link in my browser manually but it vanishes there too.

Comment: Its I?&autoplay=1 not just ?&autoplay=1

Comment: The URL may already have `?` so adding it blindly would ignore the added part. In those cases you'll only need `&autoplay=1`. However, Chrome doesn't start playing in background tabs, this is a recent change they made.

Comment: Its not just being added blindly tho "I?&autoplay=1" is the code youtube used to add to the end of the link when selecting that you wanted it to autoplay although this function isn't on youtube anymore it still works the same. but yes like you said probably a browser issue

Comment: @wOxxOm |?&autoplay=1 also doesn't work. So according to you there is no way I can autoplay the video?

Comment: The only way i could see it working now is if the link loaded in the current tab sorry i couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: @Paul thank you, at least you cut short my time which I might have wasted in finding the solution which doesn't exist.

Comment: No problem but it was wOxxOm that mentioned chrome not autoplaying in new tabs i can't take the credit for that lol